# Is it possible to set two starting values when sorting array using usort()?

Tags: php, sorting

```
$currency[0] = '$';
$currency[1] = 'WON';
$currency[2] = 'A$';
$currency[3] = '€';
$currency[4] = '¥';
```

I want to sort `$currency` using `usort()`. But I want `$` to be first and then `¥` be the second and then the rest will be sorted alphabetically. Is it possible using `usort()` ?

Comment: No matter where `$` and `¥` position will be? either left or right?

Comment: @RahilWazir what I want is when ascending, '$' comes first then '¥' comes second then alphabetical for the rest. When descending  '$' comes last then '¥' is second to the last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you may use `sort` with some `array_*` functions:

```
$prime = array('$', '¥');
$matches = array_intersect($currency, $prime);
$currency = array_diff($currency, $prime);
sort($currency);
$currency = array_merge($matches, $currency);
```

**UPDATE:**

Alternative solution using `usort`:

```
$prime = array('$', '¥');
usort($currency, function ($a, $b) use ($prime) {
    $i1 = array_search($a, $prime);
    $i2 = array_search($b, $prime);
    if ($i1 !== false || $i2 !== false)
        return $i2 === false || $i1 !== false && $i1 < $i2? -1 : 1;
    return $a < $b? -1 : ($a == $b? 0 : 1);
});
```

Comment: do you think its possible to create a custom function for usort() that will solve my problem?

Comment: @Alex Coroza Using `usort` is the must?

Comment: not really, but I need usort(), because actually I have associative array and I used usort for sorting other fields.

Comment: `$i2` or `$i1` will be undefined variable either of the `array_search` condition fails.

Comment: @hindmost I tried your updated solution and I got error, just like Rahil Wazir said

Comment: @Rahil Wazir Thanks for the note. Although it is not quite so. Only `$i2` would be undefined if the 1st `array_search` condition fails. Updated